# how i can position the text inside div make next to image?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to build Ebay register form.
On top I want to move the sign-in text to the right next to Ebay pic
tried float and text-align and none is work

[image: screenshot]

**HTML**

```
<div class="top1">
  <img src="pic/eb.png"/>
  <P id="sigin">Already a member?<a href="https://signin.ebay.com">Sign in</a></P>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top1{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100;
}

#sigin{
  float:right;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: the best way to accomplish this is by using the flexbox tool in CSS. do some reading on that, you will be a CSS master and not have to rely on position and float anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flexbox

just tested this and it works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <div class="top1">
        <img src="pic/eb.png"/>
        <P id="sigin">Already a member?<a href="https://signin.ebay.com">Sign in</a></P>
    </div>




      <style>
        .top1{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: 25%;
            width: 100;
        }

        #sigin{
            text-align: right;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:18px;
        }
      </style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a float right, the signin tag should be put before the image. Oh, please use `<p>` instead of `<P>`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
<div class="top1">
 <img src="pic/eb.png"/>
 <p id="sigin">Already a member?
  <a href="https://signin.ebay.com">Sign in</a>
 </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top1 {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100;
  display: flex;
}

#sigin {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Position:

```
.top1 {
  position: relative;
 }

#sigin {
 margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Hi Kaslan Use this one hope this will work for you

```
.top1{
        display:inline;
         height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
}
img{
  display: inherit;

}

p {
  display: inherit;
  text-align:right;
}
#sigin{

  text-align: right;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

### Html will remain same

```
 <div class="top1">
  <img src="pic/eb.png"/>
  <P id="sigin">Already a member?<a href="https://signin.ebay.com">Sign in</a></P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ul` and make work like a row and set elements in it and set `float:left` to it.Below snippet is working properly, but I don't have image src that's why logo is empty, it will work fine on your device.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul li{
float:left;
}
.top1{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='top1'><img src="pic/eb.png"/></li> 
  <li><P id="sigin">Already a member?
<a href="https://signin.ebay.com">Sign in</a></P></li>
</ul>
```